# Start Websphere Liberty in Debug mode and connect via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee, remote-debugging, websphere-liberty

I am searching for a way to start the Websphere Liberty profile in debug mode from the command line? I want to be able to start Liberty, so that it is listening for debug connections on a specific port. Then I would like to connect to Liberty from Eclipse, so that I can step through and debug the server code running in Liberty.

I've tried integrating Liberty into Eclipse and using the Eclipse 'Servers' view. This works great and I can start and stop Liberty using debug mode. Unfortunately, this method does not satisfy my use case because the build process uses tools external to Eclipse.

Essentially, I need a way to do this via the command line.

I tried creating a jvm.options file for Liberty and starting it, but I still can't connect to the port I specified. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but thus far I haven't figured it out.

[This page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html) has some info on jvm.options

Answer (score 11):

The [Administering the Liberty profile from the command prompt](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html) page describes how to do this:

```
[bin]$ export WLP_DEBUG_ADDRESS=7778
[bin]$ ./server debug
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 7778
```

You can then connect from Eclipse using [Remote Debugging](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cremdbug.htm?cp=1_2_12).